# Adding sub components to a styled component with flow typing

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, styled-components

I'd like to add sub components to a styled components similar to what is reference [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/246#issuecomment-297861297)

So something like this:

```
Text = styled.div`
  ${({color}) => color && `color: ${colors[color]};`}
`

Text.H1 = Text.withComponent('h1');
...
```

The catch is I want do this with flow typing.

Here is where I am at so far:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled, {css, withTheme} from 'styled-components';
import type {ReactComponentFunctional, Theme, ReactComponentStyled} from 'styled-components';

type Props = {
  color?: "blue" | "green"
};

const Text = ReactComponentStyled<*> & SubComponents<*> = styled.div`
  ${({color}) => color && `color: ${colors[color]};`}
`

Text.H1 = Text.withComponent('h1');
```

The type error occurs at `const Text`.

```
Cannot assign template string to Text because:
 • all branches are incompatible:
    • Either property H1 is missing in $npm$styledComponents$ReactComponentStyledStaticPropsWithComponent [1] but
      exists in SubComponents [2].
    • Or property H1 is missing in object type [3] but exists in SubComponents [2].
    • Or property H1 is missing in React.StatelessFunctionalComponent [4] but exists in SubComponents [2].
    • Or property H1 is missing in statics of $npm$styledComponents$ReactComponent [5] but exists in
      SubComponents [2].

     src/component/base/Text/Text.js
     43│   Caption?: ReactComponentFunctional<P & {theme: Theme}>,
     44│ };
     45│
 [2] 46│ const Text: ReactComponentStyled<*> & SubComponents<*> = styled.div`
     47│   ${({color}) => color && `color: ${colors[color]};`}
     65│ `;
     66│
     67│ Text.H1 = Text.withComponent('h1');
     68│ Text.H2 = Text.withComponent('h2');

     flow-typed/npm/styled-components_v3.x.x.js
 [3] 13│   & { defaultProps: DefaultProps }
 [4] 14│   & $npm$styledComponents$ReactComponentFunctionalUndefinedDefaultProps<Props>
       :
 [5] 23│ type $npm$styledComponents$ReactComponentClass<Props, DefaultProps = *> = Class<$npm$styledComponents$ReactComponent<Props, DefaultProps>>
       :
 [1] 70│   & $npm$styledComponents$ReactComponentStyledStaticPropsWithComponent<Props, ComponentList>
```

At the moment `Text` is created, it is missing `H1`, but I've made that type optional, so my thinking is that it should work. I also don't understand why this is an error: `H1 is missing in XXX but exists in SubComponents`. Indeed that is true, but I'm intersecting `SubComponents` with the styled component type, so I'd expect this to be a reason for it to be valid.

After figuring this out, I'd like to take this a step further and add default props and a theme to the sub component.

```
Text.H1 = withTheme((props) => {
  const Component = Text.withComponent('h1');
  Component.defaultProps = {
    color: props.theme.heading,
    size: 'xxLarge',
    weight: 'medium',
  };
  return <Component {...props} />;
});
```

Styled-component 3
Flow: 0.70
React 16

Note: I know styled components 4 has been released with the added `as` attribute (which replaces `withComponent`), but version 4 does not currently have a libdef file to work with. It's also in beta.